# How to work around Eclipse neon 4.6 removal of org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility

Tags: eclipse, compatibility, eclipse-neon

Eclipse Neon (4.6) release removed org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility, see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=476405 where this was mentioned.

Several of our plugins depend on this, and now will not install into this version of Eclipse.

Is there an easy workaround for this, short of reworking these plugins to remove this dependency, which may be a large task?

Comment: What are you using that was in this plug-in?

Comment: eg:
http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.team.git/commit/?id=1bf1c17ab4070679d47112a2a69ba3967e27c508

Answer (score 2):

`org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility` is the compatibility layer for Eclipse 2.x (before OSGi: no *META-INF/MANIFEST.MF*, only *plugin.xml*, etc.). Eclipse 3.0 was released with this compatibility layer 2004.

Just remove this dependency and look for compile errors. Probably, there will be none and you are done.

Comment: I removed the dependency, and it compiled without error, and installed, but didn't intialize properly.  I guess I have to go thru and update that part.

Comment: Maybe _org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility_ is referenced also in _features.xml_ files and in the _config.ini_ file. Or the initialize issue is not releated to this.

Answer (score 1):

To migrate our plugins, I did the following:

1) remove the dependencies on org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility, org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.auth

2) In the instructions to the maven bundle plugin, changed the Bundle-Activator 
value from org.eclipse.core.internal.compatibility.PluginActivator to the plugin class itself, which now can have start / stop methods, in place of older startup and shutdown methods.

3) Changed the plugin's 1-argument constructor (which depended on the no-longer-available compatibility classes) to a 0-argument constructor.

4) found various alternatives for old version 2 ways of doing things, like getting the plugin's unique identifier (e.g. replace descriptor.getUniqueIdentifier() with getBundle().getSymbolicName())