# Install AspectJ Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, aspectj

I'm trying to get started with aspect oriented programming.
I'm using latest eclipse (currently 12-2019)

```
public aspect Observer {

}
```

This Results in an error
`Syntax error on token "aspect", interface expected`

According to *https://www.eclipse.org/ajdt/downloads*

I added
*http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/43/update*

as an update site to eclipse

[image: Eclipse AspectJ Install Site]

However eclipse tells me that some parts could not be installed

[image: Install Error]

It looks Like some parts are missing

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software being installed: AspectJ Development Tools
>   2.2.3.e43x-RELEASE-20130627-0800 (org.eclipse.ajdt.feature.group 2.2.3.e43x-RELEASE-20130627-0800)   Missing requirement: AspectJ 1.7.3.20130613144500-a (org.aspectj.ajde 1.7.3.20130613144500-a) requires 'osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility 0.0.0'
>   but it could not be found   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: AspectJ Compiler 1.7.3.20130613144500-a (org.aspectj.feature.group 1.7.3.20130613144500-a)
>       To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.aspectj.ajde [1.7.3.20130613144500-a,1.7.3.20130613144500-a]   Cannot satisfy
>   dependency:
>       From: AspectJ Development Tools 2.2.3.e43x-RELEASE-20130627-0800 (org.eclipse.ajdt.feature.group 2.2.3.e43x-RELEASE-20130627-0800)
>       To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.aspectj.feature.group [1.7.3.20130613144500-a,1.7.3.20130613144500-a]

How could I Get Aspects to run in Eclipse?
Could you help me out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem caused by the removal of `org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility` plugin from Eclipse 4.6 .

Read more about [this problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37993222/how-to-work-around-eclipse-neon-4-6-removal-of-org-eclipse-core-runtime-compatib).

**The correct solution is to:**

Install `AspectJ` from the correct [download link](https://www.eclipse.org/ajdt/downloads/index.php).

The most updated to Eclipse 4.10 is:  http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/410/dev/update

**Another solution is to:**

1. Uninstall Eclipse.
2. Install Eclipse 4.3 (matching your `AspectJ` version) .
3. Retry AspectJ install.

**The more complex solution is:**

1. Locate and build/extract `org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility` jar file from [Maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility).
2. Put `org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility` jar file into Eclipse plugins directory.
3. Run `eclipse` in `--clean` mode to rebuild and register the added plugin.
4. Retry AspectJ install.

You might encounter more missing dependencies for `org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility`, eventually will have to load all the related plugins (long effort).

Comment: thx your solution to use aspectj 4.10 worked fine for me. Thx for your help :)